# OptionMenu callback not passing string or variable as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, arguments, optionmenu

I have a simple form that I have built using tkinter. One of my widgets is a text option menu that allows the user to select 1 of 4 corporate or entity types. The widget straight after that requires the corporate or entity registration number

Logically if the user selects "Sole Proprietor", there is no reg number required as Sole Proprietors don't have reg numbers, so if this the case and the user selects "Sole Proprietor", I want the reg number widget to disappear.

So what I do is trace the OptionMenu Variable and if and pass it to the call back as can be seen below:

```
# Organisation Type (Drop List)
CurrentRowXAlignment += 3
OrgTypeLabel = tk.Label(SetUpWindow, text="Organisation Type:", font=('​Helvetica', 11, 'bold'))
OrgTypeLabel.place(x=ColumnXAlignment1, y=CurrentRowXAlignment, anchor=LabelAnchors)
OrgType = tk.StringVar(SetUpWindow)
OrgType.set(client_data_list[2])
OrgTypeEntry = tk.OptionMenu(SetUpWindow, OrgType, "Private Company (\"(Pty) Ltd\")",
                             "Public Company (\"Limited\")",
                             "Closed Corporation (\"cc\")", "Sole Proprietor")
OrgTypeEntry.place(x=ColumnXAlignment2 - 2, y=CurrentRowXAlignment - 3, anchor=EntryBoxAnchors)
OrgTypeEntry.bind("<Tab>",MovetoNextField)
OrgType.trace("w", lambda *args, org_type=OrgType.get(): ShowRegNumber(org_type, *args))
CurrentRowXAlignment += RowGap
```

The call back function is as follows:

```
def ShowRegNumber(org_type, *args):

    if org_type == "Sole Proprietor":
        CoRegNumLabel.forget()
        CoRegNumEntry.forget()
    else:
        pass
```

For some reason the org-type is not passing - I have tried to debug and it keeps passing '' and therefore is keeps going to the "else" no matter what option on the menu is selected.

Anyone have an idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you should use `OrgType.get()` inside function `ShowRegNumber()` - in current code it gets value from `OrgType.get()` only once - at start - not when you chnage value in OptionMenu.

Comment: you don't need `trace` but `OptionMenu(..., command=...)`

Comment: `else:pass` is useless. You don't have to use `else` if you don't have code in this part.

Comment: Thank you @furas. Could you please possibly show me the `command=` I would need to use to pass the OrgType through... that is were I am failing

Comment: see code in my answer - it sends selected value to function automatically and you don't have to use `OrgType.get()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use in `lambda`

```
 org_type=OrgType.get()
```

then it gets value `OrgType.get()` only once - at start - and it assign this value.

You could use

```
 lambda *args: ShowRegNumber( OrgType.get(), *args)
```

but more readable is to use it in function

```
 def ShowRegNumber(*args):

     org_type = OrgType.get()
```

but even better is to use

```
tk.OptionMenu(..., command=ShowRegNumber)
```

and then you get selected value as the only argument in `ShowRegNumber`

```
def ShowRegNumber(org_type):
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def show_reg_number(selected):
    print(selected)

# --- main ---

setup_window = tk.Tk()

client_data_list = [
    'Private Company ("(Pty) Ltd")',
    'Public Company ("Limited")',
    'Closed Corporation ("cc")', 
    'Sole Proprietor',
]
    
org_type = tk.StringVar(setup_window)
org_type.set(client_data_list[2])

org_type_entry = tk.OptionMenu(setup_window, org_type, *client_data_list, command=show_reg_number)
org_type_entry.pack()
    
setup_window.mainloop()
```

---

**BTW:**

I used lower case names for variables and function because of [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)